# How to force specific group permissions (r/w) on files created in a directory structure?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory set up on a Linux server such that I'd like all files within it to be readable and writeable for a specific group.

So far, I've done `chmod g+s mygroup parent`, and I can see that all files inherit this group when created within this directory.

However, it does not force the `g+rw` permission, and so it is possible for a user to write a file into that directory such that others do not have read and/or write access to it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `mygroup`? Because of its name I expect a group but the syntax of `chmod g+s mygroup parent` doesn't fit. This obfuscates the question slightly.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the answer is to use ACLs to set a default:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::- /path/to/parent
```